# Ruby on Rails 5.8 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am following the rubyonrails guide. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def index
   @posts = Post.all
 end

 def new
 end

 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
 end

 def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

 private

 def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
 end 

end
```

My index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Text</th>
</tr>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The error I receive

```
Showing c:/Sites/blog/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb where line #9     
raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):


   <th>Text</th>
 </tr>

 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= post.title %></td>
     <td><%= post.text %></td>
```

As you can see my variable "@posts" under def index correlated with my variable "@posts.each do |post|". Not sure why this is not working.

Comment: does your model contain any data?

Comment: I followed rubyonrails guide and made created the post model 

   $ rails generate model Post title:string text:text

It created several files. One of which is post.rb. It contains the following:

    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

Comment: create a post first, then try to display it.

Comment: i've created several new posts. Six posts to be exact. I can see each individual post by going to [link] http://localhost:3000/post/1 and so on. As long as i keep changing the ID parameter, I can see my postings but when I go to 

[link] http://localhost:3000/posts . It displays

Template is missing
Missing template posts/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Sites/blog/app/views"

Comment: that means you need to create a view for this.  you need an index.html.erb file in your views directory

Comment: Under my C:\Sites\blog\app\views . I have 3 folders
"Layouts" 
"Posts" has
new.html.erb
and show.html.erb
"Welcome"
has index.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a view AND put it in the right directory.

In the `app/views/posts/` directory, make a new file called `index.html.erb` then put the following code in there.

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Text</th>
</tr>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `app/views/posts` instead of `app/posts/views`?

Comment: YES! Thank you!!! I had my index.html.erb app/views/welcome/index.html.erb. All i had to do was create another copy at app/posts/views/.THANK YOU SOOO MUCH !!!!